# Run 3 promises, then run the last promise once the others finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Im writing a nodejs controller.

I have a whole set of promises where each of them get data from different queries

I want to start them all (because they take different time to complete) and once they are all finished, THEN I want to start my priceCalc function which uses all the data collected.

I looked at a lot of guides and examples, but I dont understand the promise.all and how it could work in my case?

Also, what if one of them fails, it should return an error?  They must all complete for the priceCalc function to start.

(im a newbie to promises, so please make it simple if you can :-)))

```
var findPrice = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
    priceTable.findOne........

var movePrice = function (data) {
    priceArray = data......

findPrice       
    .then(movePrice)
    .then(fulfilled => console.log('findPrice FINISHED!!!'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error.message));        


var findhotdeal = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
    hotdealTable.aggregate.........

var movehotdeal = function (data) {
    hotdealArray = data;.......     

findhotdeal       
    .then(movehotdeal)
    .then(fulfilled => console.log('findhotdeal FINISHED!!!'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error.message));


var calculatePrice = function () {
    // Use the data from the previous promises once they all finished

}
```

Comment: I'd say you want something like `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then((results) => { doThingsWithResults})` - if any of the "arrayOfPromises" fails, the .then wont be called (you'll need a `.catch` to handle errors)

Comment: @JaromandaX so how do I insure that all steps of each promise is kept?`
Im not quite sure how that array would look

Comment: all steps? so you need results of findPrice, movePrice, findhotdeal and movehotdeal?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes thats true - unless there is another way to move the data from MongoDB into an array variable.  I tried doing it inside the find functions but it wont allow it. the move functions are just to move the data to a global array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the resolved values of all 4 promises

```
var findPrice = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
    priceTable.findOne........

var movePrice = function (data) {
    priceArray = data......

var findhotdeal = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
    hotdealTable.aggregate.........

var movehotdeal = function (data) {
    hotdealArray = data;.......     

var calculatePrice = function ([fp, mp, fh, mh]) {
    // fp == resolved value of findPrice
    // mp == resolved value of movePrice
    // fh == resolved value of findhotdeal
    // mh == resolved value of movehotdeal
}

Promise.all([findPrice, findPrice.then(movePrice), findhotdeal, findhotdeal.then(movehotdeal)])
    .then(calculatePrice)
    .catch(err => { /* handle errors here */})
```

Note:

```
var calculatePrice = function ([fp, mp, fh, mh]) {
    // fp == resolved value of findPrice
    // mp == resolved value of movePrice
    // fh == resolved value of findhotdeal
    // mh == resolved value of movehotdeal
}
```

is ES2015+ shorthand for

```
var calculatePrice = function (r) {
    var fp = r[0],
        mp = r[1],
        fh = r[2],
        mh = r[3];

    // fp == resolved value of findPrice
    // mp == resolved value of movePrice
    // fh == resolved value of findhotdeal
    // mh == resolved value of movehotdeal
}
```

> Given that movePrice and movehotdeal are not asyncrhonous

```
var findPrice = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    priceTable.findOne........
});

var findhotdeal = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    hotdealTable.aggregate.........
});

var calculatePrice = function ([fp, fh]) {
    priceArray = fp;
    hotdealArray = fh;
    // fp == resolved value of findPrice
    // fh == resolved value of findhotdeal
}

Promise.all([findPrice, findhotdeal])
    .then(calculatePrice)
    .catch(err => { /* handle errors here */})
```

Comment: Ahhh!!  so you can actually use .then inside the promise.all - I did not know that.  This is actually a really good solution, it will allow me to do all the steps I want inside each promise and then end with calculating price.  Nice Jaromanda!!

Comment: How do you get each function to return the result to calculatePrice?  Dont you have to do any code for that or?

Comment: note: the values in the array passed to `Promise.all` can be a mix of promises and non-promises - in this case, they'll all be promises (as .then returns a promise)

Comment: I understand the mix and the return - but not the ([fp, mp, fh, mv])... how are they passing data to the last function?

Comment: `function ([a,b,c,d]) { ... code ... }` is ES2015+ shorthand for `function (arr) { var a = arr[0], b = arr[1], c = arr[2], d = arr[3]; ... code ...}`

Comment: Ohh... so once a promise is resolved, it automatically parses the result to the .then function?

Comment: If thats the case, then this is a really good solution - Im gonna try it at once :)

Comment: if the value returned in `.then` callback is a promise, then the promise returned by `.then` takes on the result of the returned promise. Otherwise, the promise returned by `.then` resolves to the value returned in the `.then` callback - I think :p regardless, `.then` returns a promise

Comment: @torbenrudgaard one question for you ... is the code in `movePrice` and `movehotdeal` asynchronous in nature? if not, then the above can be done a little simpler

Comment: No all the move did was to move the value to a var hotdealArray = [];... pretty stupid solution when it can be done automatic by letting the promises return the results to .then - your method is WAY smarter than what I made!!

Comment: I've added the code given the fact that the move* functions are synchronous and probably don't return anything extra you need in calculatePrice - note, removed the move* functions altogether

Comment: Thats exactly what I also did just now - and IT WORKS!!! - I can cut like 50% of the code from all my controllers now.  Thank you SO much for teaching me this Jaromanda!!!  Promises are awesome! :-D

Answer (score 1):

**Primitive Promises**

I'm glad to see you've learned about `Promise.all`, but I think it's important that you can reason about how Promises work and understand that you can build these things on your own.

Your original criteria

> I have a whole set of promises where each of them get data from different queries
>
> I want to start them all (because they take different time to complete) and once they are all finished, THEN I want to start my priceCalc function which uses all the data collected.

We wish for our code to look something like below

```
all(arrayOrPromises)
  .then(values => onSuccess(values), err => onFailure(err))
```

I'll start by implementing `all` and explaining a little bit of it. Then, I'll introduce a couple other helpers to build a demo to ensure everything is working as intended.

So intuitively, `all` takes an array of *promises*, and returns a promise that resolves an array of *values*.

```
// all :: [Promise a] -> Promise [a]
const all = ps =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let pending = ps.length, result = []
    ps.forEach((p,i) => p
      .then(x => result[i] = x)
      .then(() => --pending === 0 ? resolve(result) : null)
      .catch(reject))
  })
```

We first start by returning a Promise. When given an input array of N promises, we know we need N promises to resolve before we can finally resolve the promise returned by `all`. So all we're doing is creating a container for the resolved values (`result`), attaching a `.then` to each promise that stores the resolved value, and attaching one more `.then` to check if we can finally resolve the `result` – when `pending` is `0`, there are no more pending promises, so it's time to `resolve`. Lastly, I'm attaching a `.catch` to each promise so that the outer promise is rejected **immediately** in the event that any promise fails.

---

**Demo helpers**

To construct a demo, we need to create an array of promises that take a random amount of time to complete. Of course your code will be calling actual functions that return promises, so this is just a mock of that – the reason I'm including these is so that `all` can be exhibited here in this answer as an isolated, standalone demo.

```
// fakeP :: a -> Promise a
const fakeP = x =>
  Promise.resolve(x)
    .then(log('start'))
    .then(wait(rand(5000)))
    .then(log('end'))
```

`fakeP` makes a a promise with a "fake" delay (random 0-5 seconds). For added visualisation, `fakeP` will also log when a promise *starts* and *ends*

```
// eg
fakeP(1).then(console.log, console.error)
// start 1
// <random delay>
// end 1
// 1
```

`log`, `wait`, and `rand` are not interesting but you can read their definition in the code below

---

**Runnable demo**

Click **Run** below to see the output. Most importantly, note that although the promises resolve in a nondeterministic order, the resolved values will appear in order that the promises were passed in

```js
// all :: [Promise a] -> Promise [a]
const all = ps =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let pending = ps.length, result = []
    ps.forEach((p,i) => p
      .then(x => result[i] = x)
      .then(() => --pending === 0 ? resolve(result) : null)
      .catch(reject))
  })

// fakeP :: a -> Promise a
const fakeP = x =>
  Promise.resolve(x)
    .then(log('start'))
    .then(wait(rand(5000)))
    .then(log('end'))

// wait :: Int -> a -> Promise a
const wait = ms => x =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms, x))

// label :: String -> a -> a
const log = label => x =>
  (console.log(label, x), x)

// rand :: Number -> Number
const rand = x =>
  Math.random() * x

// 5 "fake" promises with random delay (0-5 seconds each)
const promises =
  [ fakeP('a'), fakeP('b'), fakeP('c'), fakeP('d'), fakeP('e') ]

// run it
all(promises).then(console.log, console.error)

// start a
// start b
// start c
// start d
// start e
// end e
// end a
// end d
// end c
// end b
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
```

So in the example here, we're just using `console.log` as the `onSuccess` function

```
all(promises).then(console.log, console.error)
// ...
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
```

We could replace that with anything to do whatever we'd like with our values

```
all(promises).then(
  xs => console.log(xs.reverse().join('').toUpperCase()),
  console.error
)
// ...
// EDCBA
```

---

**Remarks**

Ok, so don't use `all` when `Promise.all` is precisely what you need and already provided for you. My point in writing this post though is that you don't have to feel helpless when you have a task and you're unaware of a all-in-one function that magically solves all of your problems.

There's nothing wrong with writing your *own* function to solve your problem and then later returning to your code once you learn `Promise.all` exists.